# How to test empty input?

Tags: jq

The following command finishes silently when the input is empty. How to test for empty input and do something different depending on whether the input is empty or not?

```
$ jq -e -r .data < /dev/null
$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: Pleases follow the [mcve] guidelines as much as possible.  Do you want to be able to use the return code ($?) to determine whether the input is empty?  And what do you mean exactly by "empty"?   Is it important to distinguish between /dev/null, a file with a single newline, a file with two blank lines .... ?

Comment: Which version of `jq` are you using? I get the exit status `4` in this example, and that's the documented behaviour of `-e`, but I am running a development build. It looks like released versions had a bug that was fixed a few years ago: https://github.com/stedolan/jq/commit/6d3d2750ec1e076cd86189b8fcfe1b760e2207c7 Since jq 1.6 was released in 2018, I think this fix might not have been released?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use the `-s` option and test for the empty array:

```sh
jq -s 'if . == [] then "empty" else .[0].data end' </dev/null
```

```json
empty
```

But what else should be considered an empty input? As JSON ignores newlines etc., there could be an actual input which is considered an empty JSON:

```sh
echo | jq -s 'if . == [] then "empty" else .[0].data end'
```

```json
empty
```

While the expected case will pass...

```sh
echo '{"data":1}' | jq -s 'if . == [] then "empty" else .[0].data end'
```

```json
1
```

...other non-empty cases may not be caught as with the empty case

```sh
echo '{"other":1}' | jq -s 'if . == [] then "empty" else .[0].data end'
```

```json
null
```

However, to elaborate more, you'd need to specify what "do something different" means. If you wanted to fail, like with the `-e` option but with a custom error message, you could read in the whole input as raw text using the `-Rs` option, then try to convert it to JSON using the `fromjson` builtin, and react upon that if it failed using the `?` and `//` operators:

```sh
jq -Rs 'fromjson? // error("Bad input") | .data' </dev/null
```

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Bad input
```

```sh
echo | jq -Rs 'fromjson? // error("Bad input") | .data'
```

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Bad input
```

```sh
echo '{"data":1}' | jq -Rs 'fromjson? // error("Bad input") | .data'
```

```json
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```sh
jq -ne 'input? // null'
```

```
$ echo {}  | jq -ne 'input? // null' >/dev/null; echo $?
0

$ echo ''  | jq -ne 'input? // null' >/dev/null; echo $?
1

$ </dev/null jq -ne 'input? // null' >/dev/null; echo $?
1
```

---

If you also want to check that `.data` isn't missing and isn't `null` (or `false`), you can use

```sh
jq -ne 'input? // null | .data'
```

```
$ echo '{"data":123}'  | jq -ne 'input? // null | .data' >/dev/null; echo $?
0

$ echo '{"data":null}' | jq -ne 'input? // null | .data' >/dev/null; echo $?
1

$ echo {}              | jq -ne 'input? // null | .data' >/dev/null; echo $?
1

$ echo ''              | jq -ne 'input? // null | .data' >/dev/null; echo $?
1

$ </dev/null             jq -ne 'input? // null | .data' >/dev/null; echo $?
1
```